# Alinhar texto no bottom dentro de uma div

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Estou criando um layout e distribuindo várias `<div>` com o recurso de flexbox, alguém saberia me dizer como faço para o conteúdo desta `<div>` que será uma palavra, ficar alinhada ao centro e no bottom desta `<div>`?

Obrigado!

Comment: Posta seu código para ajudarmos da melhor forma possível

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o

```
flex: 1;
align-self: flex-end;
```

no conteudo da sua div